# How to mock a Flowable with map and compose?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am writing unit test for my reactive api. I am unable to mock a flowable. Below is the code for which I am trying unit.

```
Flowable.fromPublisher(a.publish(event)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.compose(filterInstance(B.class))
.map(B.method())
.subscribe();
```

In junit I am mocking

```
Publisher<>test = new Publisher<>(){
@Override
public void subscribe(Subscriber s){
s.onNext(B);
}
}
when(a.publish(any()).thenReturn(test);
```

But it is giving me null pointer . Can anyone help me in how to mock this type of reactive code? I don't want to test this flowable but mainly want to test the map thing.

Comment: Why mock it instead of make a real flowable?

Comment: But how should I test it then?  How will I ensure the coverage?

Comment: Can you just do `when(a.publish(any()).thenReturn(Flowable.just(B))`?

Comment: Pass a real flow of data.  There's no need to mock, just pass some real data in a flowable.